# GMail API search results using 'after' not returning full results

Tags: api, search, gmail, gmail-api

I'm having a bit of trouble with a GMail API implementation.  I'm running a query that is returning only a partial data set of emails.  (This is the first time that I am retrieving emails for this account, so I want to retrieve some deeper historic records as a base, before moving forward with a daily increment retrieval.)

I am using the 'after' operator, and using the Unix Epoch seconds as the value.

When I enter the same "after:" search into the Search bar on the Google website for this account, I get 598 emails (for 60 days back), and 292 emails (for 30 days back).  When I use the API, I only get 103 (and this is after letting it paginate over all the results; the initial 'page' is only 100 email IDs; the 2nd Page then has 3.)

Here are a couple of the query URLs that I am hitting:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=after%3A1619045685

https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=after%3A1616453916
```

Any ideas?  Is there an internal limit that I'm hitting?  Is there some setting that I haven't set?

Thanks.

Comment: No responses yet, and only 6 views in 4 days?  I'm a bit surprised... did I post this in the wrong place somehow?  I got here from the GMail API Documentation pages...

Comment: Oh man... only 10 views in over 1 month!  :(

Comment: Hmmm... running it today, I actually appear to be getting way more messages than I thought I would.  Instead of ~300 I got >800.  So now it's the opposite problem!  :(